# HTML OBJECT tag used in a tabbed UI & onMouseDown

Tags: html, object, tabs, onmousedown

I have built an HTA with a set of panels/tabs to display different elements of a task. The panels are hidden using 'style.display="none"' and displayed using 'style.display="block"'. Almost the entire codeset is held in separate functions which then write to the "page" using '.InnerHTML'.

This works very well (I have a whole collection of HTAs using this technique). In the HTA in question, I have embedded a treeview and listview object using the OBJECT tag which, again, works fine, except...the onMouseDown (and similar) events don't seem to fire in this scenario. In a conventional, non-tabbed HTA, however, this works fine. I can take action on right-click, etc., etc. Note also that nodes in the treeview and elements in the listview are displayed correctly and, in the case of the former, nodes expand and collapse on mouse clicks as expected. In the latter, rows can be selected, checkboxes checked, etc.

I added some debug code to trap and display the object's ID (using window.event.srcelement.id) and discovered that no ID seemed to be processed, which I *really* don't understand!!

The code is *far* too long to post here: I'm hoping someone will instantly identify what the problem might be or, at least, be able to provide a direction to start looking for a solution.

Lastly, my preferred language is VBScript but I can decipher well-written Javascript in order to translate it into VBS.

Comment: We'll really need an example of your code for this. The description is just way to generic. Try creating a minimal example. Quite often the process of trying to find the minimal requirements for reproducing the problem also lead you to the solution.

Comment: You *did* ask! :-)

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A271422F94A9A5BA!51801&authkey=!AD-Lx-CUbDrJdW8&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Please have a look at how to make a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I have a minimalist implementation of an HTA with the treeview and it works flawlessly. It has code which tracks the mouse and displays the X/Y coordinates, etc. That code has been lifted more or less verbatim into the HTA with the tabbed UI but doesn't seem to trigger any of the mouse events.

Comment: To wit:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A271422F94A9A5BA!51802&authkey=!AOS76aQNsD3YOFk&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: I just added an event listener to the treeview object, to no avail.